# In Python: How to compare and generate new column if split String matches the column value?

Tags: python, pandas, string, dataframe, split

Have got a dataframe like below:

**Input Dataframe:**

```
Store   Products    located_products    
11      AA          AA, CC
11      BB          AA, CC
11      CC          AA, CC
12      AA          BB
12      BB          BB
12      CC          BB
```

**Scenario:**
At store level, '*located_products*' value will be unique - which has to be split by each string and to be compared with '*Products*' column. If value matches, new column '*Prod_Flag*' should holds value 'Y', if not leave empty.

**Required Dataframe:**

```
Store   Products    located_products    Prod_Flag
11      AA          AA, CC              Y
11      BB          AA, CC              
11      CC          AA, CC              Y
12      AA          BB
12      BB          BB                  Y
12      CC          BB
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`Series.str.split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) with comapre by [`DataFrame.eq`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.eq.html) and [`DataFrame.any`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.any.html) and pass to [`numpy.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
m = df['located_products'].str.split(', ', expand=True).eq(df['Products'], 0).any(1)
df['Prod_Flag'] = np.where(m, 'Y', '')
print (df)
   Store Products located_products Prod_Flag
0     11       AA           AA, CC         Y
1     11       BB           AA, CC          
2     11       CC           AA, CC         Y
3     12       XX               YY          
4     12       YY               YY         Y
5     12       ZZ               YY
```

EDIT:

Solution for test values per groups:

```
print (df)
   Store Products located_products
0     11       AA           AA, DD
1     11       DD           AA, CC
2     11       CC           WW, ZZ
3     12       XX               WW
4     12       WW               ZZ
5     12       ZZ               AA
    
#convert first to columns to index and located_products to multiple columns
df1 = df.set_index(['Store','Products'])['located_products'].str.split(', ', expand=True)
print (df1)
                 0     1
Store Products          
11    AA        AA    DD
      DD        AA    CC
      CC        WW    ZZ
12    XX        WW  None
      WW        ZZ  None
      ZZ        AA  None
      
#test per Store if matching
m = df1.groupby('Store').apply(lambda x: x.isin(x.index.get_level_values(1))).any(axis=1)
df['Prod_Flag'] = np.where(m, 'Y', '')
print (df)
   Store Products located_products Prod_Flag
0     11       AA           AA, DD         Y <- match AA per 11
1     11       DD           AA, CC         Y <- match CC per 11
2     11       CC           WW, ZZ           <- no match
3     12       XX               WW         Y <- match WW per 12
4     12       WW               ZZ         Y <- match ZZ per 12
5     12       ZZ               AA          <- no match
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution. Did this solves my problem at Store Level?? Because, 'Products' can be same across all Stores. So have to compare for each store. Question Edited accordingly for more understanding. Kindly refer!

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively this can also work but answer by @jezrael was quite good

but my solving

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

s=df['located_products'].str.split(',')
df['loc1']=s.str[0]
df['loc2']=s.str[1]
df['Prod_Flag']=np.where((df['products'].eq(df['loc1'].str.strip(' ')))| 
(df['products'].eq(df['loc2'].str.strip(' '))),"Y"," ")
```